# Can't seems to redirect to another url after the alert "You have successfully registered!"

Tags: javascript

After successful alert, page is not redirecting to other page

```js
function displayAlertNRedirect() {
  alert("You have successfully registered!");
  window.location.href = "ThankyouPage.html";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayAlertNRedirect()">Show alert & redirect</button>
```

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vLjbxaph/

Comment: Your code snippet works. So there's something else going on.

Comment: guys is there any way for me to show my whole codes? i m having difficulties posting the whole codes here

Comment: the console did not show any errors? and i put those 2 lines of codes in a function does that matter?

Comment: you could post a link to a git repo. however if you show too much code dont expect people to look at it. try to find the minimal example demonstrating your problem.